# perl string exact match in another string

Tags: string, perl

If I want to find a specific (constant) string in another string, does the =~ do the job or is it better to use another operator? Should I use /^ $/?

```
use constant {
MYSTR => "HGjfslT",
};

if (MYSTR =~ $rec_str){
...
}
```

Cheers,

Carol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While regex can do what you want, you may want to try the [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function because that is specifically what the function is for and it is faster than regex. Use regex for more complex pattern matching.

```
if ( index( MYSTR, $rec_str ) != -1 ) {
    ....
}
```

Doing `/^ $/` in the regex is to get an exact match. In that case, use `eq`:

```
if ( MYSTR eq $rec_str ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all answers.

My question concerned to find the string in another with a longer length.

Now the question is that how can I search for the same string but allowing one wildcard (a character of a specific set) on any position of MYSTR?

So again using MYSTR =~ /$rec_str/, or index, then consider that any character of HGjfslT could be taken from (A, C, W, Z) but one at a time and the rest of MYSTR should be the same?

For ex
HGjfslT, HAjfslT, HGjfslW, are accepted but not HGnfslT

Comment: If you want to use *wildcards* or some sort of pattern match, then regex is your tool. Have a go at a solution for these new requirements, and I can see if you have done it right.

Comment: I don't have an appropriate solution because in addition to $rec_str, I think I should match MYSTR with 7 patterns of "HGjfslT" (7 is the length of "HGjfslT") and replace 1 character to [A,C,W,Z] like /[A,C,W,Z],"GjfslT"/, "H",[A,C,W,Z],"HjfslT" which doesn't seem to be correct nor elegant.

Comment: So I thought to build up the constant string as follows:


`code`

$mystr="";
 foreach my $i (1..length(MYSTR)){
  $mystr .=/[HGjfslTACW]/;
 }

`code`

but of course, it doesn't work. I wanted to build the string by taking any character in HGjfslTACW, 7 times.

Any suggestion?

Comment: just having a go at it myself, I think you should approach the problem by working out what is different between the strings, rather than what is the same. As a simple solution, iterate through each character from a string and compare it with the corresponding character from the other string, assuming they're the same length.

Comment: I can't because if the number of allowed characters instead of ACWZ are a lot, there will be a lot of comparisons.

alternatively, I thought the following

foreach my $i (0..length(MYSTR)){
  push @arr, substr(MYSTR,0,$i).".".substr(MYSTR,$i+1);
 }

for ($i = 0; $i<scalar(@arr);$i++){
   $ind = index($recstr[$r], $arr[$i]);
   last if ($ind != -1);
  }

What to do so that index takes . as any character that is in the elements of @arr? Because as it is because of ., it doesn't match

Many thanks

Comment: I would post this as a new question because your latest question is completely different to the original question. `index` is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 0):

`=~` is perfectly fine for this type of task.

If you want the exact match then use `^` and `$` to match the start and end.

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/rnv7Od)</kbd>

```
use constant {
MYSTR => "HGjfslT",
};
my $rec_str = "jfslT";
if (MYSTR =~ /$rec_str/){
     print "Matches!";
}
if (MYSTR =~ /^$rec_str$/){
     print "This will not match!";
}
$rec_str = "HGjfslT";
if (MYSTR =~ /^$rec_str$/){
     print "This will match!";
}
```